# PostgreSQL doesn't log

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, log

I'm using `ArchLinux` and `PostgreSQL` 9.4.4 and have enabled the logging in the config file:

```
$ sudo egrep -v "^[[:blank:]]*($|#|//|/\*| \*|\*/)" /var/lib/postgres/data/postgresql.conf

max_connections = 1024          # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 128MB          # min 128kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option
logging_collector = on      # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
log_directory = '/tmp'      # directory where log files are written,
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' # log file name pattern,
log_file_mode = 0644            # creation mode for log files,
log_error_verbosity = verbose       # terse, default, or verbose messages
log_statement = 'all'           # none, ddl, mod, all
log_timezone = 'Asia/Jakarta'
datestyle = 'iso, dmy'
timezone = 'Asia/Jakarta'
lc_messages = 'en_CA.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_CA.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_CA.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_CA.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

then restart or reload the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
sudo systemctl reload postgresql
```

the loaded settings:

```
postgres=# SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%log%';
            name             |            setting             
-----------------------------+--------------------------------
 log_autovacuum_min_duration | -1
 log_checkpoints             | off
 log_connections             | off
 log_destination             | stderr
 log_directory               | /tmp
 log_disconnections          | off
 log_duration                | off
 log_error_verbosity         | verbose
 log_executor_stats          | off
 log_file_mode               | 0644
 log_filename                | postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
 log_hostname                | off
 log_line_prefix             | 
 log_lock_waits              | off
 log_min_duration_statement  | -1
 log_min_error_statement     | error
 log_min_messages            | warning
 log_parser_stats            | off
 log_planner_stats           | off
 log_rotation_age            | 1440
 log_rotation_size           | 10240
 log_statement               | all
 log_statement_stats         | off
 log_temp_files              | -1
 log_timezone                | Asia/Jakarta
 log_truncate_on_rotation    | off
 logging_collector           | on
 syslog_facility             | local0
 syslog_ident                | postgres
 wal_log_hints               | off
(30 rows)
```

the `/tmp` permission:

```
$ ll /tmp/ 
total 11656
drwxrwxrwt 22 root root       580 Jun 29 10:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root      4096 Jun 10 08:04 ../
...
```

the `/tmp` usage:

```
$ df | grep /tmp
tmpfs            8159996    31204   8128792   1% /tmp
```

doing some query on `psql`, but the `/tmp/postgresql-*` still doesn't show up. What can I do to find which part that prevent log from being created?

**EDIT 1**

the result of `journalctl -u postgresql`

```
Oct 08 09:13:53 xxx postgres[19861]: LOG:  00000: redirecting log output to logging collector process
Oct 08 09:13:53 xxx postgres[19861]: HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "/tmp".
Oct 08 09:13:53 xxx postgres[19861]: LOCATION:  SysLogger_Start, syslogger.c:645
Oct 08 09:13:55 xxx systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL database server.
```

Comment: Why would you log to `/tmp` anyway? I don't see why it wouldn't work with your configuration as shown, though.

Comment: just for development/debugging, so it would be cleared every reboot

Comment: If you check your PostgreSQL related processes, do you see a `postgres: logger process`?

Comment: @dezso yes `postgres: logger process` exists on `ps ax` output

Comment: Just to be sure, can you verify the loaded settings: `SELECT name, settings FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE 'log%'`?

Comment: @MatheusOl http://pastie.org/10269087 it's as expected

Answer (score 3):

The logging collector tries to capture `stderr` and write it to a file.  But it looks like systemd wins the redirecting war, and sends the output to the journal.  You can check the systemd journal with:

```
journalctl -u postgresql
```

The systemd configuration is in `usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`. I've tried various settings for `StandardError`, but none seems to allow the regular Postgres logging to do its work.

Comment: With the exact same permissions, the `postgres` user can write to `/tmp/` without a problem on our hosts.

Comment: @dezso: That is unlikely... did you test with `sudo -u postgres echo hi > /tmp/test.txt`?  That runs `echo` as postgres but the redirect as `root`. The correct syntax is `sudo -u postgres bash -c 'echo hi > /tmp/test.txt'` and it should show a "permission denied" error.

Comment: No, I am logged in as `postgres`, no need to sudo.  Aren't the DB processes running basically the same way?  How does opening a new shell come into this picture?  (Note that I am on Ubuntu, but that should not make a big difference, AFAIK.)

Comment: When permissions on /tmp are `drwxrwxrwt` as shown, that implies that every user can write into it (rightmost `w` corresponding to others), which is the normal situation. There's nothing wrong here.

Comment: @Andomar `$ sudo -u postgres echo hi > /tmp/test.txt`
works fine `cat /tmp/test.txt` gives `hi` | here's the journalctl output: `http://pastie.org/10264195`

Answer (score 2):

Your setting is `log_destination=stderr`
And log_collector redirects stderr to /dev/null (hardcoded, because of their pretty hacky way of parent-child pipe redirect).
You will need to set `log_destination=csvlog` or `syslog` or both.